# Difference between bundle and package

Tags: meaning, difference

"Bundle" and "package" both mean different items put together and sold as one unit. What is the difference between them in the following sentences?

1. Starbucks is offering **a lunch bundle** for busy workers in London.

   https://www.thesun.co.uk/money/4971251/starbucks-is-launching-a-3-99-meal-deal-but-it-doesnt-include-a-hot-drink/

   Can I use "package" here instead?
2. Turn yourself into a marketable brand with this $19 training **package**.

   https://thenextweb.com/offers/2019/08/05/turn-yourself-into-a-marketable-brand-with-this-19-training-package/

   Can I use "bundle" here instead?
3. LSAC also now offers **packages** at a slight discount that include the LSAT registration fee, CAS fee, and school reports. The two packages are as follows:

   Package 1: LSAT (including LSAT Writing), CAS, 1 Law School Report = $430

   Package 2: LSAT (including LSAT Writing), CAS, 6 Law School Reports = $650

   https://magoosh.com/lsat/2019/how-much-does-the-lsat-cost/

   Can I use "bundle" here instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When speaking figuratively, it may help to think of a "bundle" as a group of various objects wrapped together:

[image]

and a "package" as some objects placed in a box and sometimes wrapped with paper:

[image]

"Bundle" can feel more loose and haphazard, which (as in your example) may be a kind of marketing gimmick.  Calling something a "bundle" implies the vendor isn't all that concerned about the price, that they're trying to group a bunch of things together because they just want to get rid of them -- in other words, the buyer is getting a *special deal*.

Meanwhile "package" requires more effort and planning. Something like a ["package tour"](https://www.friendlyplanet.com/vacation-packages/) implies that the trip has been carefully organized to include everything travelers will need -- flights, hotels, meals, guides, etc. -- so they don't have to worry about additional expense.

In all of your examples, you can substitute "bundle" for "package", and vice-versa, but it may subtly change the nuance.

Answer (score 5):

In this kind of use, "bundle" and "package" are pretty much interchangeable. "Bundle" implies that several things which are also sold or provided separately are being sold as a unit, while "package" might be more likely to be be used where some or all of the things are only available in the joint offer. But this distinction is not strictly observed.

Both uses are figurative, of course. A "bundle" originally meant several things wrapped up or rolled up together, and "package" a thing or group of things wrapped or boxed or enclosed.

Comment: @Brad  this kind of comment is better addressed (and is being addressed) on [meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/).  Citing sources is useful in some answers, but superfluous in others, particularly when the answer involves *interpretation* rather than *definition*.  Still, I agree, the best answers are the ones which offer external validation.

Comment: @ Andrew. Thanks for the reply, Is meta a chat? Where is the link?

Comment: @Brad  [ELL Meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/) is a Stack Exchange to talk about issues related to ELL,  https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/.  I included the a hyperlink to the relevant discussion in the word "meta" above, but maybe it's difficult to see on whatever device you use.  There is also an ELL chat of sorts, but I'm not entirely familiar with how it works.

Answer (score 2):

> Starbucks is offering a lunch bundle for busy workers in London.
>
> Can I use "package" here instead?

No. It wouldn't work.
It could be confused with 'packaged lunch' --> 'packed lunch', which would indicate that there is a set option only, that you can take away in a package (i.e. not for dine-in). In a packed/packaged lunch, you might find a set menu within that package. E.g. Package 1: apple, cold drink, tuna sandwich; Package 2: pear, cold drink, ham sandwich. Whereas with a bundle, you'd have more options to choose from. E.g. choose any piece of fruit, any cold drink (can be substituted with a hot drink for a small extra fee), and any sandwich from this menu of sandwiches.

> Turn yourself into a marketable brand with this $19 training package.
>
> Can I use "bundle" here instead?

No. It wouldn't work. 'Bundle' sounds less formal, less professional, and more haphazard.

> LSAC also now offers packages at a slight discount that include the LSAT registration fee, CAS fee, and school reports. The two packages are as follows:
>
> Package 1: LSAT (including LSAT Writing), CAS, 1 Law School Report = $430
>
> Package 2: LSAT (including LSAT Writing), CAS, 6 Law School Reports = $650

Can I use "bundle" here instead?

No. As above.